# Org-mode amend new info to the task

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Here's the situation that I'm trying to describe, and would like to reflect in the org file:

Suppose you started a task, but while working on it you realized that the description of the task must be amended in a way that it justifies that task to be extended. Still you don't want to lose the original estimate, just for historical purposes, so, roughly, what I would like to have would be:

```
* STARTED Do something seemingly easy
  DEADLINE: <2013-06-09>
  This should be a breezy

  AMENDED: <2013-06-10>
  Looks like this will require more effort
```

The agenda buffer would use the latest date in the task, but it would be still "interesting" to know the original estimate after the task was finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many options](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html#In_002dbuffer-settings) in org-mode for logging or adding notes whenever a task properties change.

Check for example `lognotereschedule`, which will ask you for a note when rescheduling a task.

You can choose to store all notes and status changes in a special drawer called `LOGBOOK` in order to avoid clutter.